# COM function returns E_POINTER

Tags: c++, com

As newbie it is very hard to learn COM concept.Please explain me following error.Why it is happening I have com code with following function body.

```
STDMETHODIMP CCollectionBase::put_InputCollectionInterface(
    IUnknown *InputTagInterface)
{
    ICollection* inputCollectionInterface;
    HRESULT hr = QueryInterface(__uuidof(ICollection),
        (void**)&inputCollectionInterface);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    //m_inputCollectionInterface  is global variable of ICollection    
    m_inputCollectionInterface = inputCollectionInterface;
    return S_OK;
}
```

And i am calling function in following way.

```
ITag* inputTagInterface;
//InternalCollection is ICollectionBase object
hr = InternalCollection->put_InputCollectionInterface(inputTagInterface);
```

but hr i get is `E_POINTER`. Why is it `E_POINTER`?

Comment: You get `E_POINTER` because you are lucky. `inputTagInterface` is an uninitialized pointer variable. This has nothing to do with COM at all - this is very basic C++. COM returns an error code (if it can). C++ crashes (unless it cannot).

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for reply you mean to say the parameter that i passing is not initialize?

Comment: @IInspectable how to initialize parameter then?

Comment: looks like the argument is not used in put_InputCollectionInterface, also how did you get the InternalCollection object ? I suspect the latter is the problem, not inputTagInterface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Garbage In, Garbage Out", you pass a random pointer into the function, you do a wrong call inside, so expect weird things back.

Incorrect things are:

```
STDMETHODIMP CCollectionBase::put_InputCollectionInterface(
    IUnknown *InputTagInterface)
{
    ICollection* inputCollectionInterface;
    // 1. You are calling QueryInterface() on the wrong object,
    //    most likely you were going to query the interface of
    //    interest of the argument pointer
    if (!InputTagInterface) return E_NOINTERFACE;
    HRESULT hr = InputTagInterface->QueryInterface(
          __uuidof(ICollection), (void**)&inputCollectionInterface);
    if (FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    //m_inputCollectionInterface  is global variable of ICollection
    m_inputCollectionInterface = inputCollectionInterface;
    return S_OK;
}

ITag* inputTagInterface;
// 2. You need to initialize the value here to make sure you are passing
//    valid non-NULL argument below
hr = InternalCollection->put_InputCollectionInterface(inputTagInterface);
```

Since your `E_POINTER` is coming from `CCollectionBase::QueryInterface` method, I suppose you have other issues on the code you did not quote.